# Assign .on('click') in a for loop to each array element individually

Tags: jquery, loops, foreach

Is there a possibility to toggleText() for each element of the array separately?

Right now, when clicked, the values are changed for every single element at the same time and I'd like to go over them one by one as they're clicked.

```
$(function() {
    var jap = ["kau", "matsu", "shiru"];
    var eng = ["to buy", "to wait", "to know"];
    var tds = [$('#td1'), $('#td2'), $('#td3')]
    
    for (i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        $(tds[i]).on('click', function(){
            for(i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
            $(tds[i]).toggleText(jap[i], eng[i]);
            }
        });
     }
});
```

Ideally, I'd like to change the text inside a table cell on each individual click for each array element.

-- edit:

Here's the HTML with the table:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="tb">
         <tr>
            <td>Godan Verbs</td>
            <td>V2</td>
            <td>Ichidan Verbs</td>
            <td>V2</td>
            <td>Irregular Verbs</td>
            <td>V2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td>kau</td>
             <td>kai-</td>
             <td>taberu</td>
             <td>tabe-</td>
             <td>kuru</td>
             <td>ki-</td>
           <tr>
              <td>matsu</td>
              <td>machi-</td>
              <td>miru</td>
              <td>mi-</td>
              <td>suru</td>
              <td>shi-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>shiru</td>
              <td>shiri-</td>
              <td>oshieru</td>
              <td>oshie-</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>kaku</td>
              <td>kaki-</td>
              <td>neru</td>
              <td>ne-</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>oyogu</td>
               <td>oyogi-</td>
               <td>kangaeru</td>
               <td>kangae-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>hanasu</td>
                <td>hanashi-</td>
                <td>okiru</td>
                <td>oki-</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>shinu</td>
                 <td>shini-</td>
                 <td>sakeru</td>
                 <td>sake-</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>yomu</td>
                  <td>yomi-</td>
                  <td>kotaeru</td>
                  <td>kotae-</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>asobu</td>
                   <td>asobi-</td>
                   <td>iru</td>
                   <td>i-</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>                
 </table>
```

Here's additional meaning of the words I'd like to display:

```
const jap2en = {"kau":"to buy", "matsu":"to wait", "shiru":"to know", "kaku":"to write", "oyogu":"to swim", "hanasu":"to talk", "shinu":"to die", "yomu":"to read", "asobu":"to play", "taberu": "to eat", "miru": "to look", "oshieru": "to teach", "neru": "to sleep", "kangaeru": "to think", "okiru": "to get up", "sakeru": "to avoid", "kotaeru": "to answer", "iru": "to be/exist", "kuru": "to come", "suru": "to do"};
```

I also added ids to the tds that are supposed to show the meaning like this for each individual td:

```
<td id="td1">kau</td>
<td>kai-</td>
<td id="td2">taberu</td>
// and so on
```

and changed the js code to this:

```
const $tds = $("#tb td[id]");
$("#tb").on("click", "td[id]", function() { ... }
```

However, as I mentioned in the comment, that one fragment changes the structure of the table and makes tds appear in wrong places. This fragment specifically:

```
$tds.each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(jpArr[i])
    $(this).data("lang","ja")
 })
```

If removed, the code works but the cells require two clicks to show the meaning.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com) because your setup is overly complicated. And if you go the jQuery-way your problem will also be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have jQuery - use its power

It is not recommended to loop to add eventListeners in JavaScript, jQuery or not.

```js
const jap2en = {"kau":"to buy", "matsu":"to wait", "shiru":"to know", "kaku":"to write", "oyogu":"to swim", "hanasu":"to talk", "shinu":"to die", "yomu":"to read", "asobu":"to play", "taberu": "to eat", "miru": "to look", "oshieru": "to teach", "neru": "to sleep", "kangaeru": "to think", "okiru": "to get up", "sakeru": "to avoid", "kotaeru": "to answer", "iru": "to be/exist", "kuru": "to come", "suru": "to do"};
const jpArr = Object.keys(jap2en); // just the Japanese keys
const en2jap = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(jap2en).map(a => a.reverse())); // makes a reverse lookup

$(function() {
  const $tds = $("#tb td");
  $("#tb").on("click", "td", function() { // delegation
    const text = $(this).text();
    const lang = $(this).data("lang");
    const langArr = lang === "ja" ? jap2en : en2jap;
    const langText = langArr[text];
//    console.log(text,lang,langText,langArr[text])
    if (langText) {
      $(this).text(langText);
      $(this).data("lang",lang === "ja" ? "en" :"ja" );
    }  
  });
  $tds.each(function(i) {
    $(this).data("lang","ja")
  }) 
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Godan Verbs</th>
          <th>V2</th>
          <th>Ichidan Verbs</th>
          <th>V2</th>
          <th>Irregular Verbs</th>
          <th>V2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tb">
        <tr>
          <td>kau</td>
          <td>kai-</td>
          <td>taberu</td>
          <td>tabe-</td>
          <td>kuru</td>
          <td>ki-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>matsu</td>
          <td>machi-</td>
          <td>miru</td>
          <td>mi-</td>
          <td>suru</td>
          <td>shi-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>shiru</td>
          <td>shiri-</td>
          <td>oshieru</td>
          <td>oshie-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>kaku</td>
          <td>kaki-</td>
          <td>neru</td>
          <td>ne-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>oyogu</td>
          <td>oyogi-</td>
          <td>kangaeru</td>
          <td>kangae-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>hanasu</td>
          <td>hanashi-</td>
          <td>okiru</td>
          <td>oki-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>shinu</td>
          <td>shini-</td>
          <td>sakeru</td>
          <td>sake-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>yomu</td>
          <td>yomi-</td>
          <td>kotaeru</td>
          <td>kotae-</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>asobu</td>
          <td>asobi-</td>
          <td>iru</td>
          <td>i-</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

---

simpler version

```js
const jap = ["kau", "matsu", "shiru"];
const eng = ["to buy", "to wait", "to know"];

$.fn.extend({ // extending jQuery to have a toggleText
  toggleText: function(a, b) {
    return this.text(this.text() == b ? a : b)
  }
});

$(function() {
  $("#tb").on("click", "tr", function() { // delegation
    const idx = $(this).index();
    $(this).find("td").eq(0).toggleText(jap[idx], eng[idx]);
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Godan Verbs</th>
      <th>V2</th>
      <th>Ichidan Verbs</th>
      <th>V2</th>
      <th>Irregular Verbs</th>
      <th>V2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr>
      <td>kau</td>
      <td>kai-</td>
      <td>taberu</td>
      <td>tabe-</td>
      <td>kuru</td>
      <td>ki-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>matsu</td>
      <td>machi-</td>
      <td>miru</td>
      <td>mi-</td>
      <td>suru</td>
      <td>shi-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>shiru</td>
      <td>shiri-</td>
      <td>oshieru</td>
      <td>oshie-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>kaku</td>
      <td>kaki-</td>
      <td>neru</td>
      <td>ne-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>oyogu</td>
      <td>oyogi-</td>
      <td>kangaeru</td>
      <td>kangae-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>hanasu</td>
      <td>hanashi-</td>
      <td>okiru</td>
      <td>oki-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>shinu</td>
      <td>shini-</td>
      <td>sakeru</td>
      <td>sake-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>yomu</td>
      <td>yomi-</td>
      <td>kotaeru</td>
      <td>kotae-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>asobu</td>
      <td>asobi-</td>
      <td>iru</td>
      <td>i-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Do you perhaps have any idea why this fragment:

`
$tds.each(function(i) {
    $(this).text(jpArr[i])
    $(this).data("lang","ja")
  })
`

breaks the structure of a table? tds are all mixed up when I apply this code. When I remove the mentioned fragment, then it's structured as expected, but it requires two clicks to show the meaning of the word.

Comment: I set the text to the value of the lookup table and then set the data-attribute to whatever the current language in the cell is

Comment: The loop is to set the value of the cell to begin with so we do not have to fill the table by hand. Show YOUR html if you want my code to work with your html

Comment: Let me edit my initial question and include the html

Comment: added the html to the question and some more clarification

Comment: Ok, I have changed both versions to toggle the translation on the first cell

Comment: Awesome, thank you a lot. One more question – it seems that cells in the second and third columns are not responding to this code, what would be the reason for this issue?

Comment: Only the cells in the first column are changing on click, the rest stay the same

Comment: I did not code that - I had only a little idea of what you wanted

Comment: I just told you I ONLY respond to click in the first column because you only have translation of the first three row's first cell

Comment: Right, I should've been more specific; there's a full list of words and their translations in my question. I added it together with the HTML code when editing.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

If you want to achieve on every click the corresponding text based on index of array to toggle then i believe you have to just get rid of the inner for loop you have used.

also you just have to save the ids without $ and ()

which makes it like this

```
$(function() {
    var jap = ["kau", "matsu", "shiru"];
    var eng = ["to buy", "to wait", "to know"];
    var tds = ['#td1', '#td2', '#td3'];
    
    for (i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
        $(tds[i]).on('click', function(){                
            $(this).toggleText(jap[i], eng[i]);                
        });
     }
});
```

**EDIT**

i just made it working like this (looping event listeners though i guess):

```js
$(function() {
  var jap = ["kau", "matsu", "shiru"];
  var eng = ["to buy", "to wait", "to know"];
  var tds = ['#td1', '#td2', '#td3'];

  $("td").each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      var textToToggle = $(this).text() == jap[index] ? eng[index] : jap[index];
      $(this).text(textToToggle);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td1">kau</td>
    <td id="td2">matsu</td>
    <td id="td3">shiru</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please test your code. Click [edit], then `[<>]` and create a stacksnippet. You will see you lack a closure over the `i` and the `i` is now a global variable

Comment: It is NOT recommended to loop to add eventlisteners - especially not now it is as easy in plain JS as in jQuery